# I have an issue with my react website. I want to popup description page on clicking on specific product. But my changes are reflected all the cards

Tags: reactjs

this is my card js here i have mapped the data from my productdata file and used the states
to get my popup data on the click of more info button. But with this code i am not able to
reflect the change to only one card. I am not getting how can i only reflect this change to my
selected card.

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import Modal from '../Modal';
    import productCard from "./productData";

    function Card() {
        const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
        const openModal = (value) => { 
          setShowModal(prev => !prev)
        };

        const listitems =  productCard.map((item) =>
        <div className="card" key={item.id}>
    
            <div className="card_img">
                <img src={item.thumb} alt="img" />
            </div>
            <div className="card_header">
                <h2>{item.product_name}</h2>
                <p>{item.description}</p>
                <button className="description" onClick={() =>openModal(item.id)}>More 
                Info</button>
                <Modal showModal={showModal} setShowModal={()=>setShowModal(item.id)} />
                <p className="price">{item.price}<span>{item.currency}</span></p>
                <div className="btn">Add to cart</div>
            </div>
        </div>)
  
   
        return (
            <>   
                <h2 className="content_title">Product list</h2>
                {/* <div>{this.state.count}</div>  */}
                <div className="main_content">
                    <h3>MOBILES</h3>             
                    {listitems};
                </div>
                
                
            </>
        )
    }
    export default Card;
```

and this is my modal js:
when i click on the more info button it popups the changes with all the cards

```
import React from 'react';

const Modal = ({showModal, setShowModal}) => {
    console.log(showModal)
    return (
        <>  
        
                {showModal ? 
                <div>hello</div> : null
                }
        </>
    )
    
}

export default Modal
```

Comment: @RohitNagpal How can i reflect this change to my clicked button

Comment: @RohitNagpal Basically I want is that, when i click on that 'more info' button, it should show the 'hello' under that button on the card which has that button..... not on all the cards

Answer (score 2):

Each card item from your "listitems" and its child Modal **shares the same showModal state**. I would recommend creating a separate "Card" component which has its own "showModal" state, controlled by its own button, and pass the "item" as a prop inside that component through a similar mapping of "productCard" like you've done.